# Ada - Skipping Whitespace using look_ahead

Tags: whitespace, ada, regex-lookarounds

I have a procedure, that in theory, should be skipping whitespace using a look_ahead loop.  Problem is, it's not working, if there's any whitespace in the input file, it is adding it to the array of records.  I think my logic is correct, but could use another pair of eyes to let me know what I'm missing, and why it's not working.

```
PROCEDURE Read(Calc: OUT Calculation) IS
  EOL: Boolean;
  C: Character;
  I: Integer := 1;
BEGIN
  LOOP
     LOOP
        Look_Ahead(C, EOL);
        EXIT WHEN EOL or C /= ' ';
        Get(C);
     END LOOP;
     EXIT WHEN ADA.Text_IO.END_OF_FILE;    
     Look_Ahead(C, EOL);
     IF Is_Digit(C) THEN
        Calc.Element(I).Kind := Number;
        Get(Calc.Element(I).Int_Value);
     ELSE
        Calc.Element(I).Kind := Symbol;
        Get(Calc.Element(I).Char_Value);
     END IF;
     Calc.Len := Calc.Len+1;
     IF Calc.Element(I).Char_Value = '=' THEN
        EXIT;
     END IF;
     I := I+1; 
  END LOOP;
END Read;
```

EDIT:  If any of the other procedures, the code for the record etc is needed for an answer, let me know and I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

For `Ada.Text_IO.Look_Ahead`, [ARM A.10.7(8)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p8) says

> Sets End_Of_Line to True if at end of line, including if at end of page or at end of file; in each of these cases the value of Item is not specified. Otherwise, End_Of_Line is set to False and Item is set to the next character (**without consuming it**) from the file.

(my emphasis) and I think the "without consuming it" is key. Once `Look_Ahead` has found an interesting character, you need to call `Get` to retrieve that character.

I hacked this little demo together: I left end-of-file to exception handling, and I called `Skip_Line` once end-of-line’s been seen because just `Get` wasn’t right (sorry not to be more precise!).

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.IO_Exceptions;
procedure Justiciar is

   procedure Read is
      Eol: Boolean;
      C: Character;
   begin
      --  Instead of useful processing, echo the input to the output
      --  replacing spaces with periods.
      Outer:
      loop
         Inner:
         loop
            Ada.Text_IO.Look_Ahead (C, Eol);
            exit Outer when Eol;   -- C is undefined
            exit Inner when C /= ' ';
            Ada.Text_IO.Get (C);   -- consume the space
            Ada.Text_IO.Put ('.'); -- instead of the space for visibility
         end loop Inner;
         Ada.Text_IO.Get (C);      -- consume the character which isnt a space
         Ada.Text_IO.Put (C);      -- print it (or other processing!)
      end loop Outer;
      Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;       -- consume the newline
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;        -- clear for next call
   end Read;

begin
   loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put ("reading: ");
      Read;
   end loop;
exception
   when Ada.IO_Exceptions.End_Error =>
      null;
end Justiciar;
```

Comment: You answer put me onto the correct solution. Thank you for posting the comment about it not consuming the character.  While I knew that it didn't consume it, I don't think I had spent enough time thinking about how it was working.  Ultimately the solution was to add a `Get(c)` followed by `IF C /= ' ' THEN` statement in the existing ELSE.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better to read an entire line and parse it than to try to parse character by character. The latter is usually more complex, harder to understand, and more error prone. So I'd suggest something like

```
function De_Space (Source : String) return String is
   Line : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String (Source);
begin -- De_Space
   Remove : for I in reverse 1 .. Length (Line) loop
      if Element (Line, I) = ' ' then
         Delete (Source => Line, From => I, Through => I);
      end if;
   end loop Remove;

   return To_String (Line);
end De_Space;

Line : constant String := De_Space (Get_Line);
```

You can then loop over `Line'range` and parse it. Since I'm not clear if

```
Get(C);
Get(Calc.Element(I).Int_Value);
Get(Calc.Element(I).Char_Value);
```

represent 1, 2, or 3 different procedures, I can't really help with that part.